# rendering cgm graphics in fop with jcgm plugin

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Hey guys I know that this is a little obscure, but I'm using fop xsl-fo to build pdfs and I'm having a problem rendering some cgm graphics. I'm using a plugin called "jcgm" to render the cgms, so I'm assuming these graphics are just not supported by the library. Do you guys know of a solution to this? Or maybe another plugin I could use with fop? Also, would it be possible to write some java code of my own to get the job done? Any suggestions for a solution would be appreciated, thanks.

-Dave

Comment: I have tried asking the people who built the plugin but I cannot get a response. I have also tried finding a way to convert the cgms into a different vector graphic like a .svg, but I cannot find a way to do that in java code either.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Exactly what have you tried? Are there any error messages? According to http://jcgm.sourceforge.net/howto.html#pdf, producing a PDF file containing CGM graphics should be very easy.

Comment: Most of the cgm files do show up, but there are about 5 or 6 that don't. It seem that maybe they are of a different type or signature. I do not have the exact error messages on hand now, but they say something alone lines of "this graphic type is not supported." I guess my question should be, are there any other plugins I could use with fop that might offer a broader range of support?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest 2 things to sort this out.

- As you know, `cgm` graphics are not natively supported by FOP. There is `jcgm`, but it has its limitations - and it turns out its not easy to find out what exactly the limitations are for a given `cgm` (see: http://jcgm.sourceforge.net/features.html).
- So, AFOP copes very feebly with `cgm` graphics. How about converting the `cgm` parts beforehand? There seem to be a bunch of converters available (e.g. http://www.cgmlarson.com/convert_CGM_files_to_image_formats_aerospace.html - without having a closer look, just took the first one I found) to do away with `cgm` alltogether.

Especially if you are using `XSLT` to produce the `XSL-FO` in the first place, those stylesheets is where you would convert graphics to a more acceptable format.